# Where are variables passed into the view in Django?

Tags: django, view

I'm refactoring code in a Django view. I'm working with a view with the below arguments:

```
def title_views(request, key, group, sort):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, group=group, main_id = key)
    default_sort = sort
```

I know by default each view should have the `request` argument. But in terms of `key, group, sort`, where can I expect these items to be passed? Is it through the template that the view is called in? I come here for help because the documentation isn't that clear on this, at least in my experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are URL parameters. Likely the URL that links to this view looks like:

```
    path('<str:key>/<str:group>/<str:sort>/', title_views)
```

or with a regex, something like:

```
    re_path(r'(?P<key>\w+)/(?P<title>\w+)/(?P<sort>\w+)/')
```

If you thus visit a page like `foo/bar/qux/` it will pattern match on the path, and thus call the function with `'foo'` for `key`, `'bar'` for `title`, and `'qux'` for `sort`.

Usually the URL parameters thus contain data that determine how to filter, order and render the content.